# Ciclo while para comparar valores de dos tablas distintas no funciona como lo esperaba

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo una comparación de dos tablas que contienen números de extensiones. La primera tabla tiene todos los números de extensiones disponibles y en la otra se encuentran los números de extensión que se están utilizando actualmente.

Mi intención es mostrar en un `<select>` los números de extensión que están disponibles únicamente. Les comparto mi código.

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM extensionesmicrosip"; //saca todos los numeros de extension
    $query = "SELECT * FROM nuevosingresos"; //saca los numeros de extension en uso
    
    $filas = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); //consulta para sacar los numeros de extension existentes
    $rows = mysqli_query($conexion, $query); //consulta para sacar los numeros de extension en uso
    
    $extensiones_disponibles = array(); //aqui se van a guardar las extensiones que no esten en uso
    
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    
    while($extensiones = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas)){ //ciclo que guarda en la variable $extensiones todas las extensiones existentes
        
        $j++; //variable para saber cuantos elementos hay en el arreglo $extensiones
        echo $j;
        
        while($asignadas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)){ //ciclo que guarda en la variable $asignadas todas las extensiones en uso
            
            if($extensiones['extension'] != $asignadas['extension_msip']){ //condicion que checa si cada una de las "n" $extensiones coincide con alguna de las $asignadas
                
                $extensiones_disponibles = $extensiones['extension']; //Aqui se guardan las extensiones que no coincidieron, o sea que estan disponibles
                $i++; //variable para saber cuantos elementos hay en el arreglo $asignadas
                echo $i;
                
            }
            
        }
            
    }
    var_dump($extensiones_disponibles);
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El listado de extensiones disponibles lo puedes obtener con una sub consulta:

```
SELECT extension
FROM extensionesmicrosip
WHERE extension NOT IN (
    SELECT extension_msip
    FROM nuevosingresos
)
```

A la consulta principal le pasas la condición de que solo muestre las extensiones que no estén en la subconsulta.

Puedes crear un `array` con el resultado y asignarlo a la variable `$extensiones_disponibles` o puedes construir directamente los `option`.

Te dejo un ejemplo, pero la maquetación del `html` te la dejo a ti ya que desconozco la manera en que la haces.

```
$sql = " SELECT extension
        FROM extensionesmicrosip
        WHERE extension NOT IN (
            SELECT extension_msip
            FROM nuevosingresos
        )";
$filas = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$extensiones_disponibles = '<select>';
while($extensiones = mysqli_fetch_assoc($filas)){
    $extensiones_disponibles .= '
        <option value="'.$extensiones['extension'].'">'.$extensiones['extension'].'</option>
    ';
}
$extensiones_disponibles .= '</select>';
echo $extensiones_disponibles;
```